# Есть ли какие-то стандарты для пропуска строки в коде?

Tags: java

Не секрет, что код, написанный без создания пустых строк (например, между описаниями методов), выглядит чересчур нагроможденным и трудночитаемым. Так как же его правильно разделять (чтобы это соответствовало стандартам красивого кода)?

Comment: В андроид студио есть сочетание клавиш CTRL+ALT+L, которое отформатирует вам красиво код

Comment: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.6.1-vertical-whitespace

Comment: На самом деле, хороший вопрос, т.к. оформление кода для его читаемости - крайне важная тема. Я пишу на c# в основном, но стили написания кода не особо отличаются от java. Могу приложить очень хорошую ссылку на документацию от майков, на которую я частенько раньше поглядывал, чтобы корректно оформлять код https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: Вспомнил вот про эту ссылку ещё - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-introduction.html. Тут только про java. Это в дополнение к ответу Кирилла Малышева